# React change grid layout onClick animation

Tags: css, reactjs, typescript, material-ui

Is it possible to animate a grid layout change on click in React?

For example, I have the following component:

```
import { Box, Button, styled, useMediaQuery } from "@mui/material";
import Row1 from "./Row1";
import React from "react";

const gridTemplateLargeScreens = `
    "d d d d d d"
    "e e e e e e"
    "a a b b c c"
    "a a b b c c"
    "a a b b c c"
    "a a b b c c"
    "f f f f c c"
    "f f f f c c"
    "f f f f c c"
    "f f f f c c"
`;

const testing = `
    "d d d d d d"
    "e e e e e e"
    "b b b b c c"
    "b b b b c c"
    "b b b b c c"
    "b b b b c c"
    "b b b b c c"
    "b b b b c c"
    "b b b b c c"
    "b b b b c c"

`;

interface RootProps {
  diffFormat: boolean;
}

const DashBoardWrapper = styled("div", {
  shouldForwardProp: (prop) => prop !== "diffFormat",
})<RootProps>(({ theme, diffFormat }) => ({
  width: "100%",
  height: "100%",
  display: "grid",
  gap: "1rem",
  padding: "10px 0px 10px 0px",
  overflow: "auto",
  [theme.breakpoints.down("xl")]: {
    gridTemplateColumns: "repeat(6, Math.calc(100%/6))",
    gridTemplateRows:
      "repeat(10, minmax(Math.calc(100%/10), Math.calc(100%/10)))",
    gridTemplateAreas: diffFormat ? testing : gridTemplateLargeScreens,
  },
  [theme.breakpoints.up("lg")]: {
    gridTemplateColumns: "repeat(6, Math.calc(100%/6))",
    gridTemplateRows:
      "repeat(10, minmax(Math.calc(100%/10), Math.calc(100%/10)))",
    gridTemplateAreas: diffFormat ? testing : gridTemplateLargeScreens,
  }
}));

const Dashboard = () => {
  const [diffFormat, setDiffFormat] = React.useState<boolean>(false);
  const handleChange = () => {
    setDiffFormat((diffFormat) => !diffFormat);
  };
  return (
    <DashBoardWrapper diffFormat>
      <Button onClick={handleChange}>Change Format</Button>
      <Row1 />
    </DashBoardWrapper>
  );
};

export default Dashboard;
```

And basically on button click, I want gridArea b to transform from a 2x4 to a 4x8 and vise versa when clicked again. Without re-render ofc, smooth animation. Is this possible?

And basically on button click, I want gridArea b to transform from a 2x4 to a 4x8 and vise versa when clicked again. Without re-render ofc, smooth animation. Is this possible?

And basically on button click, I want gridArea b to transform from a 2x4 to a 4x8 and vise versa when clicked again. Without re-render ofc, smooth animation. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

I was trying to prepare a prototype and encountered a similar situation. I ended up using [View Transitions API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/View_Transitions_API). Essentially, it instructs the browser to capture a screenshot, perform a transformation (e.g., altering grid-template-areas), capture a new screenshot, and animate the changes that occurred in between.

Here's an example:
https://codesandbox.io/s/cocky-platform-ngc97h

In my case, I was altering the grid template using setTimeout(), so no user interaction was involved. Because of that, I had to use React's flushSync to keep the DOM updated.

```
const shuffle = () => {
   flushSync(()=>{
      document.startViewTransition((_) => setShuffled(!shuffled));
   });
};
```

**Compatibility Warning!**

As of now, View Transitions API is not widely supported and probably you should avoid this. There are other solutions with better compatibility that you might want to try:

https://github.com/aholachek/animate-css-grid

https://github.com/aholachek/react-flip-toolkit